# Cual es la diferencia entre eager y lazy?

Tags: java, sql

Cual es la diferencia entre eager y lazy? cuando yo los utilizo un entity Manager recupere las entidades de una base de datos ?

Comment: Hola Daniel , puedes explicar mejor la pregunta? Añade ejemplos donde uses `eager` y `lazy`. Lee [ask] para mejorar el estado de la pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

La diferencia entre eager y lazy la puedes ver cuando tienes 2 entidades relacionadas.
Por ejemplo, si tienes una entidad llamada Ciudad, y otra habitantes...
La entidad ciudad tiene unas propiedades básicas como Id, nombre, superficie, al igual que la entidad habitante tiene las suyas.

Cuando java carga la entidad Ciudad, carga esas propiedades básicas, pero para habitantes tienes 2 opciones. Cargar todos los habitantes de esa ciudad(eagerly) o ir cargando los habitantes a demanda(lazy) cuando por ejemplo se llame a una función como por ejemplo GetHabitantes().

Como ves es cuestión de eficiencia, ya que si no necesitas ver información de los habitantes seria un derroche cargar inicialmente todos los datos de esos habitantes.